# How to update from C# to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've calculated my 'ERna', and now I want to update it to my SQL Server database. I've made the statement, but I don't quite get how I get it to update in my database from C#.

Any ideas?

```
decimal ERna = ERnu - bprijs;
lbEigenRisico.Content = ERna;

string updateQuery = "UPDATE Verzekering SET eigen_risico = @ERna";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, dbconn.Connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ERna", ERna);
```

Comment: You need to update it by ID, eg. `UPDATE tablename SET value = @newvalue WHERE id = @id` then add that as a parameter.

Comment: Not sure if you are already doing so and left it out of the code snippet, but you still need to call `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` to actually execute the command.

Comment: The first ten search results for "C# SqlCommand not updating" show plenty of hints, what have you tried?

Comment: @MilanLeew I know this question doesn't ask about this, but I would recommend you take a look at entity framework.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to open the connection and call `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: And this is why I should read comments before posting. If C.Evenhuis posts his comment as an answer, I will delete this in favor of his answer.